# Css causes Angularjs dynamic div results to Jam

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

Am trying to display angularjs results at the right hand side using css. To this effect, I have created a Css class called
**Side-Bar.**

**Here is my issue:**

when I run the angularjs code, the Css causes the result to be jamed with each other
 but If I display the result div of each User one after the other directly within html, it will be okay as per code below

```
   <li style="list-style:none;">
        <div class="sidebar" >
          <div id="sidebar-user-box1">User 1</div>
          <div id="sidebar-user-box1">User 2</div>
          <div id="sidebar-user-box1">User 3</div>
          <div id="sidebar-user-box1">User 4</div>
       </div>
   </li>
```

[image: see secreenshot]

**For Angular Js:**

Css causes angularjs result to be jamed when displayed. (Note: If I remove the css the angularjs result will be displayed but with no css to position at the right)

[image: Angularjs Result jamed]

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="myapp">
<head>
  <title></title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.6/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    var app = angular.module('myapp', []);

    app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

      $scope.arr = [{
          name: "user 1 Angualrjs"
        },
        {
          name: "User 2 Angualrjs"
        },
        {
          name: "user 3 Angualrjs"
        },
        {
          name: "User 4 Angualrjs"
        }
      ];

      $scope.collapseIt = function(id) {
        $scope.collapseId = ($scope.collapseId == id) ? -1 : id;
      }
    });
  </script>

  <style>
    .sidebar {
      width: 250px;
      position: fixed;
      height: 100%;
      right: 0px;
      top: 0px;
      padding-top: 10px;
      padding-bottom: 10px;
      border: 1px solid #b2b2b2;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <li style="list-style:none;" ng-repeat='ret in arr'>
    <div class="sidebar">
      <div> {{ret.name}}</div><br>
    </div>
  </li>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `sidebar` should be a *wrapper* around your sidebar `ul` - see the change in *markup* I have made to your code:

```js
var app = angular.module('myapp', []);
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.arr = [{
      name: "user 1 Angualrjs"
    },
    {
      name: "User 2 Angualrjs"
    },
    {
      name: "user 3 Angualrjs"
    },
    {
      name: "User 4 Angualrjs"
    }
  ];

  $scope.collapseIt = function(id) {
    $scope.collapseId = ($scope.collapseId == id) ? -1 : id;
  }
});
```

```css
.sidebar {
  width: 250px;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  right: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #b2b2b2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.6/angular.min.js"></script>

<div class="sidebar" ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <ul>
    <li style="list-style:none;" ng-repeat='ret in arr'>
      {{ret.name}}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```